# How to calculate soil moisture in a plant field with ground nodes that intersect?

Tags: soil-sensing

I have placed 5 soil moisture sensors in my field where potatoes are growing.

These soil moisture sensors give me correct soil moisture readings up to 400 meters radius from where they are placed.

That is why I have placed 5 of them. They send the data via LoRa to a Raspberry Pi.

If I am inside the radius of a soil moisture sensor I know I have correct reading.

How do I measure the soil moisture when there is radius intersection of `node_A` and `node_B`?

The point I want to use is inside the range of both `node_A` and `node_B`.
See attached image.

I want to calculate `p1`.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about the sensors themselves or radio interference?

Comment: Only the sensors. I mean each sensor has valid soil moisture reading inside a radius of 400m. So, what is the soil moisture value in point `p1` where I get 2 different values: `soil_moisture_value_1` from `node_A` and `soil_moisture_value_2` from `node_B`?

Comment: Interpolate the two measurements, based on the distance of p1 from node A and node B.

Comment: Ok, I do not know this method...What can I google search it? With what name? Can you give me a small example?

Comment: If what you say is true, that the sensors give you "correct...readings up to 400 meters" then the two readings should be the same. I'm not sure you really understand what the sensor reading means. Are you trying to say that the soil moisture is uniform over a radius of 400m? I doubt that very much, unless you are in a flood or a desert.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson: Your thought is correct. I don't want to go further cause I am writing on Electrical Engineering website....What really matters for me now is how to calculate the point `p1` where the sensors give me 2 different values... Thank you for your comment and your time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [linear interpolation.](https://theeducationlife.com/interpolation-formula/)

You have two distances:

- \$d_1\$ = distance from \$node_A\$ to \$P1\$
- \$d_2\$ = distance from \$node_B\$ to \$P1\$

You have two moisture readings:

- \$m_1\$ = moisture at \$node_A\$
- \$m_2\$ = moisture at \$node_B\$

You want \$m_3\$ - the soil moisture at \$P1\$:

$$m_3 = m_1 + (d_1 - d_2) \frac {m_2-m_1}{d_2-d_1}$$

Simple enough.

---

I don't think the results you get will be as representative as you think they will be.

[image]

That's a map of the soil moisture in my front yard.  The yard is only about 12 meters by 6 meters - that's **much** smaller than your field.  I used sixteen soil moisture sensors over the much smaller area.

I used an interpolation function from [SciPy](https://scipy.org/) to generate the charts from the sensors.

Even in that small area, the moisture varies greatly.  The black areas in the top graph represents about 15% soil moisture.  The green area represents about 60% soil moisture.

Besides variations over the area, it also varies with the temperature.  [This video](https://vimeo.com/539304410?ref=em-share) shows how the soil moisture and the temperature vary over the day.

The picture and the video are from last year.  They are part of an [on-going experiment.](https://hackaday.io/project/178004-soil-moisture-monitoring-in-a-flower-garden)

I'll be putting the sensors back out in the yard when spring rolls around again.

---

Your sensors may give you an accurate number when read via LoRa over 400 meters.

It would greatly surprise me if the number itself is valid for more than a few meters around the sensor.

Comment: Great answer! A short question. If  `m2` and `m1` are not exact numbers , but each one represents a range of values. Can I still use the above equation? For instance: `m1 = (1 to 4)` and `m2 = (3 to 5)`. The numbers are random.

Comment: You would have to apply the interpolation over the range.

Comment: I implemented interpolation to ranges, but I get as a result a range with negative values... `[x1, x2]`, where `x1 < 0` and `x2 < 0`... Any ideas?